# MongoDB Default Value when no data found

Tags: mongodb

i have this query on mongodb

```
db.meals
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            _id: { $in: [ObjectId('123'), ObjectId('1234')]},
            mealsStatus: { $ne: 'SERVED' },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$orderId',
            orderCount: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
      ])
```

the problem is when the no data matches the filter, it returns nothing,
how to make it returns like this

```
{
   '_id': 1234,
   'orderCount': 0
},
{
   '_id': 1234,
   'orderCount': 0
},
```

it will return the given id and 0 as the default orderCount.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `$unionWith` behind your current work to append zero count results for all the groups your want. Then do another `$group` to add the counts together.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$key",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$documents": [
            {
              "_id": "A",
              "count": 0
            },
            {
              "_id": "B",
              "count": 0
            },
            {
              "_id": "C",
              "count": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bvOx-a_bXXK)